# ActiveStorage url_for v.s. service_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

We have been returning links to images by supplying the service_url of the blob, which is a short lived signed URL (we are using S3 as our ActiveStorage backend). This appealed to us because we can set the expiry of the links we generate with `service_url`. However it appears that this is not the correct approach, and that we should **not** be using the service_url in this way. From the docs:

> ...This URL is intended to be short-lived for security and not used directly with users. Instead, the service_url should only be exposed as a redirect from a stable, possibly authenticated URL...

I can't find a clear opinion online, but it seems that we should instead be using the rails route helper method `url_for` to generate a permanent link to the resource, that redirects? to the service url?

Is this correct? Does `url_for` generate a permanent link that redirects to the short-lived service_url of the resource?